# Flat output vector for simple classifier neural network with keras/scikit-learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to build a simple neural network for an easy classification problem. I have just discovered the keras/scikit-learn wrapper classes, but the behavior is not exactly as expected.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

The `KerasClassifier` expects a build function for the network:

```
def build_perceptron():
    net = keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='random_uniform'),
            keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
        ]
    )
    net.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["binary_accuracy"]
    )
    return net
```

Now I can use it as follows:

```
model = KerasClassifier(
    build_fn=build_perceptron,
    epochs=100, 
    batch_size=5,
)
```

The network learns to classify perfectly. However, the predictions have shape `(n_samples, 1)` instead of `(n_samples,)`, as expected for scikit-learn:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
```

I tried to use scikit-learn functions and got 0.0 F1 scores for a classifier that should have F1 of roughly 1.0.

```
cross_val_score(
    KerasClassifier(
        build_fn=build_perceptron,
        epochs=100, 
        batch_size=5,
    ),
    X=X,
    y=y,
    scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, greater_is_better=True),
)
```

Do I need to configure the network differently to get the right output shape?

This is somewhat confusing, since the training labels were a 1-dimensional vector and there was no complaint about the shape.

Comment: The wrapper uses Keras at its core, so an output shape ( num_samples, output_dim ) is normal since the last Dense layer has 1 unit. I think it is completely normal with Keras.

Comment: However, the point of KerasClassifier is to conform to the scikit-learn API. One could of course manually `.flatten()` the output numpy array, but I want the model to be usable in code like `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` and I am not sure it is.

Comment: Got it. From [what I'm seeing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-keras-deep-learning-models-scikit-learn-python/), even if the `predict` output is not flattened, `sklearn` functions still work with `KerasClassifier` objects. Have you actually had an error?

Comment: I got weird results for F1 scores in `cross_val_score`, and I suspected it had something to do with the shape. See edit.

Comment: I ran all that with dummy data and the scores are definitely wrong. I think there's an unintended behavior which somehow doesn't throw errors. Probably the true array and target array are substracted at some point, which returns an array of shape `(n_pts, n_pts)` instead of `(n_pts,)`

Comment: So I know this doesn't solve your question but I could make it work by adding `y_pred = y_pred.ravel()` at the top of my `f1_score` function. Then the scores are right. But yes there's definitely a flaw here.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the error. This might be a case for the keras bug tracker then.